# getting facebook comment by comment id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I am trying to get details of a comment by its comment id. This comments exists in a facebook comments box plugin which I have used in a website.

I tried the facebook api explorer and using this as the input

```
1388155601440738?fields=id,from,created_time
```

I got the response I wanted

```
{
  "id": "1388155601440738",
  "from": {
    "name": "Ahmed Anas",
    "id": "599062201"
  },
  "created_time": "2014-01-06T08:12:25+0000"
}
```

Unfortunately I cant figure out how to implement this in php..

I would assume all I need to do was get the contents from

> http://graph.facebook.com/1388155601440738?fields=id,from,created_time

but I get an **Unsupported get request exception**

I also tried the php API with this code but no luck

```
$response = $facebook->api(1388155601440738);
$response = $facebook->api('/1388155601440738?fields=id,from,created_time');
```

Comment: Your comment ID doesn’t look like the one in the example on the official documentation for Facebook comments in the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/comment/

Comment: Oh.. I was getting it from the javascript api comments.create callback.. turns out the commentID field is actually NOT the comment id but the post_fbid

Answer (score 0):

I believe the comment id you are passing is incorrect. Also you have to add /comments after comment id. So the final URL for you would be something like http://graph.facebook.com/750281525001535/comments?fields=id,from,created_time. This one works fine

Comment: Thanks for the response. But if the comment id being passed was wrong, I wouldn't have received a response from the api explorer. Also, this comment is a comment from the comments box, if that makes a difference

Comment: Happy to help! Glad that you have got the solution